# Display previous activity after launching browser activity?

Tags: android, browser, android-activity, android-intent, stack

I'm got a scenario where my app has a series of activities and then opens a Browser activity. The browser activity then authenticates the user and calls back to a URL with custom scheme i.e. myapp://finished.

An intent filter is used to trigger the display on one of the existing activities. I basically want the app to go back to the activity that was displayed before the Browser activity was launched.

The problem I'm having is that the Browser activity creates a new task so when the browser calls back and my activity is loaded a new instance of it is created in the browsers task and not my app's orignal task. This results in my activity being recreated.

> ```
> Task (created by my app)
>
> 1) Activty 1
>
> 2) Activty 2
>
> Task (created by the browser)
>
> 3) Browser Activity
>
> 4) Activity 2 (new instance)
> ```

I'm aware that there are flags that can be used to resume existing activities instead of recreating them but they don't work as any new intent that is created after the browser is restricted to the browsers task stack.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by finishing the activity just after getting invoked by webview will pop up your last activity on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `Webview` or launching a 3rd party browser? In the last case, consider using a Webview

Comment: I'm using SocalLib and it creates a Web Browser activity. So I don't have controller over how it does it. It looks like I might have to write some of the auth logic myself.